# Как изменить свойство контрола из другого класса?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс Auth.cs, в нем допустим:

```
        public static void SetIsActive(bool active)
        {
        loginStartupWindow F1 = new loginStartupWindow();
        if (active == true)
        {
            F1.AuthStatusRing.IsActive = true;
        }
        else if (active == false)
        {
            F1.AuthStatusRing.IsActive = false;
        }

        }
```

И есть форма loginStartupWindow.xaml.cs. В Auth.cs нужно сделать так, чтобы при вызове метода, изменялось св-во ProgressRing'a из loginStartupWindow.xaml.cs. Ошибок не дает, но и результата тоже. + еще после закрытия программы, еще висит в процессах, пока не килльнешь.

Comment: > В Auth.cs нужно сделать так, чтобы при вызове метода, изменялось св-во ProgressRing'a из loginStartupWindow.xaml.cs. Ошибок не дает, но и результата тоже.

1. что за ProgressRing?
2. Какое его свойство должно изменяться? 
3. Как оно должно изменяться? 
4. Кто или что не дает ошибок и результата?

Comment: 1. Компонент из MetroWindow для C#.
2. IsActive
3. Вкл и выкл.
4. Компилятор не выдает ошибок, программа не показывает результат. Просто как будто ничего и не было.

Comment: При обращении к методу вы создаете каждый раз новый объект формы и благополучно его меняете (свойства), но он не имеет ничего общего с тем объектом формы, который вы видите на экране, так как это разные объекты. Простым решением будет передавать ссылку внутрь вашего статического метода на соответствующий объект формы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void SetIsActive(bool active)
    {
        loginStartupWindow F1 =            Application.Current.Windows.OfType<loginStartupWindow >().FirstOrDefault();
        F1.AuthStatusRing.IsActive = active ;
    }
```

Comment: "System.Windows.WindowCollection" не содержит определения для "OfType" и не был найден метод расширения "OfType", принимающий тип "System.Windows.WindowCollection" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: @LiveD это метод расширения класса Enumerable. Добавьте в  файл строку **using System.Linq**

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, очень выручили. Спасибо!